# Kafka delete records from the topic without using offsets but by a field of the record

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Suppose I have a topic called "batch" with 1 partition and I publish millions of records to it for processing. I have a consumer group of 3 to process those millions of records. I encounter a case where I no longer need to process certain subset of messages which satisfy a certain criteria like `age < 50`

How do I remove those messages from the topic in a programmatic way. Like I click a "Cancel" button in the UI and it should remove those subset of records from the topic whose `age < 50` so that it wont be processed by the consumers.

I know that I can remove messages by running a command line with offsets:- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-delete-records.sh

And also the Java API but again by offsets:

https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#deleteRecords-java.util.Map-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DeleteRecordsOptions-

`Delete records whose offset is smaller than the given offset of the corresponding partition`

But in my case I cannot use offsets because I only need to remove certain records and not `all records smaller than the given offset`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing that I need to point out is that you shouldn't consider data in Kafka the same thing as data in a Database. Kafka has not been designed to work in such a way ( e.g: when I click the X button, the Y records will be deleted ).

Instead, you should see a topic as a stream of never-ending data. Every record that is produced to a Kafka topic will be consumed and processed ***independently*** by the consumer.

Perceiving the topic as a stream gives you a different solution:

You can use a second topic with the filtered results in it!

```html
Streaming Diagram
                            ___ Topic A ____
--  Produced Messages -->  |                |      _______________________
                           |________________| --> |                       |
                                                  | Filtering Application |
                            ___  Topic B ___      |                       |
                           |                | <-- |_______________________|
<-- Consumed Messages --   |________________|
```

The explanation is quite simple, you produced the messages to topic A. Then you use a `Filtering Application` which will:

1. Consume your messages from topic A
2. Based on some business logic ( e.g: `age < 50`) will filter
3. Produce the filtered messages to topic B

Finally, your consumers will receive the messages from topic B.

Now, when it comes to creating the filtering application you have a couple of options:

1. Implement a basic solution using a consumer and a producer
2. Use [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)
3. Use [KSQL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/index.html)

Comment: The problem with the second filtering application is what if the cancellation is done after the messages have reached Topic B. My suspicions were true and should not consider Kafka to fit this need. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t, Kafka isn’t designed to be used like a database, it’s actually an immutable commit log. The delete records tool is used mostly for administrative tasks.

There is an exception, and that’s if you use [log compaction](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#compaction). If you have a compacted topic you can delete the value for a key by publishing a record to the topic with a `NULL` value. Compacted topics are typically used like database commit logs and you read them into some downstream service where it’s materialized like a table. The `NULL` value should resolve into a record delete.

So in your use case you would materialize your topic to a system optimized for a query like `SELECT key FROM TABLE WHERE age > 50;`, and publish records for each key with a value of `NULL` back to the Kafka topic. You could even just start your consumer at the beginning of the topic and note which records have `age > 50` and do the same thing but that’s not going to be as efficient.

Comment: In this case, I will have to keep track of the keys (which is kind of doable in my case)  and resend null value for those keys. Only issue is that the null valued messages still will come to consumers and consumers are engaged in processing messages with null values (a waste of consumer's time & resources). 

Maybe the consumers can listen on a "cancellation" topic which has a list of keys to ignore. But this will flood the consumer with a lot of keys in memory and also there is a 'check and process' at the consumer side for every incoming message.

Comment: I really don’t think adding an `if record.valeu() == null` check is a waste of resources. Please be careful not to pre-optimize!